# Problems Building 'AutomationTool' in UE5

Tags: unreal-engine5

Tldr: Builds are failing in the AutomationTool when trying to Build the Server/Client because there seem to be files missing. I don't know how to fix that.

I'm currently trying to learn different things about UE5, following some Tutorials, and trying to grasp how servers and clients are done. On that note I was following https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/setting-up-dedicated-servers-in-unreal-engine/ .
It uses the Lyra Game provided by them.

(1)Getting the Engine to run from source:

In order to Build the Server and Client they require the source version of UE, since Lyra uses 5.3 I got the 5.3 from their Github as described here https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/downloading-unreal-engine-source-code/
I'm using VS 2022 since I was already using it on my PC.
I can open the engine and everything seems to work.

(2)Getting Lyra:

Done as in https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/lyra-sample-game-in-unreal-engine/
I can open Lyra and everything seems to work.

(3)Building the Client and Server:

When trying to build the server per the tutorial I was following originally, there are always 10 modules failing to build. With the following messages:

```
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\Platforms\Android\ref\Android.Automation.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\Scripts\ref\AutomationScripts.Automation.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\BuildGraph\ref\BuildGraph.Automation.dll' could not be found 
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\CookedEditor\ref\CookedEditor.Automation.dll' could not be found 
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\Gauntlet\ref\Gauntlet.Automation.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\LowLevelTests\ref\LowLevelTests.Automation.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\LyraStarterGame\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\ref\Lyra.Automation.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\Turnkey\ref\Turnkey.Automation.dll' could not be found
Metadata file 'H:\UnrealEngine-5.3\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool\AutomationScripts\Platforms\Windows\ref\Win.Automation.dll' could not be found
```

I found out that the Automation Tool seems to have been build incorrectly, since there are files missing. When looking over forum posts they suggested rebuilding the module. I did by right-clicking on the Automation Tool.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN7SE.png)
It cannot be Build correctly and many modules fail building for the exact same files are missing.

```
35>Done building project "AutomationTool.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 25 succeeded, 10 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any errors in C# part (Automotion, BuildGraph). I had two errors there that blocked Automotion compilation:

- possible null on 'users' variable - I've added a null check to wrapping condition: `if (reportNames != null && users != null)`
- parameter count mismatch - I've added missing `{Arg}` in the log line.

With those fixed I got whole solution successfully compiled.